# Error in Swift Code?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to program a game using Spritekit in Swift. In this, the goal is to escape with his character oncoming rectangles. Now I've made an error with the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval () method (or as I believe in the addRechteck () function), so the game crashes after the first two rectangles have arisen. Where is the mistake?

```
 import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {

    var timer = Timer()
    let figur = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Punkt.jpg")
    var rechteckRechts = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")
    var rechteckLinks = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")

    func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.addRechteck), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func addRechteck(){
        let groesse = arc4random_uniform(5)+1
        print(groesse)
        switch groesse {
        case 1:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 0.5
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 1.5
        case 2:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 1.5
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 0.5
        case 3:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 1
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 1
        case 4:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 1.25
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 0.75
        case 5:
            rechteckLinks.xScale = 0.75
            rechteckRechts.xScale = 1.25
        default:
            print("Fehler in der Wahrscheinlichkeit!!!")
        }
        rechteckRechts.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + (rechteckRechts.size.width / 2), y: frame.maxY / 1.25)
        rechteckLinks.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX - (rechteckLinks.size.width / 2), y: frame.maxY / 1.25)

        let moveDown = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -5000, duration: 20.0)
        rechteckLinks.run(moveDown)
        rechteckRechts.run(moveDown)

        self.addChild(rechteckRechts)
        self.addChild(rechteckLinks)
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        figur.xScale = 0.4
        figur.yScale = 0.4
        figur.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY / 4)
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        self.addChild(figur)
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ){
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if figur.contains(location){
                figur.position = location
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ) {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if figur.contains(location){
                figur.position = location
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
2018-08-02 11:48:50.636942+0200 Blocker[34730:2152598] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'Rechteck.gif' (320 x 206)] position:{200, 1067.199951171875} scale:{1.25, 1.00} size:{400, 206} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9f41cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e356f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea68b95 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x000000010f5c2550 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 162
    4   SpriteKit                           0x000000010f5c248d -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    5   Blocker                             0x000000010da3bd87 _T07Blocker9PlaySceneC11addRechteckyyF + 2919
    6   Blocker                             0x000000010da3be64 _T07Blocker9PlaySceneC11addRechteckyyFTo + 36
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010ddc21ee __NSFireTimer + 83
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e984374 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e984032 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e983bea __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e97b604 __CFRunLoopRun + 2308
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e97aa89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011754b9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010f7b0d30 UIApplicationMain + 159
    15  Blocker                             0x000000010da3e347 main + 55
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011383fd81 start + 1
    17  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call the function addRechteck multiple times with the timer, you are attempting to add `rechtechRechts` and `rechteckLinks` to the scene when they have already been added. Reformat the function as follows:

```
@objc func addRechteck(){
    // Added these variables here
    var rechteckRechts = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")
    var rechteckLinks = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")
    let groesse = arc4random_uniform(5)+1
    print(groesse)
    switch groesse {
    case 1:
        rechteckLinks.xScale = 0.5
        rechteckRechts.xScale = 1.5
    case 2:
        rechteckLinks.xScale = 1.5
        rechteckRechts.xScale = 0.5
    case 3:
        rechteckLinks.xScale = 1
        rechteckRechts.xScale = 1
    case 4:
        rechteckLinks.xScale = 1.25
        rechteckRechts.xScale = 0.75
    case 5:
        rechteckLinks.xScale = 0.75
        rechteckRechts.xScale = 1.25
    default:
        print("Fehler in der Wahrscheinlichkeit!!!")
    }
    rechteckRechts.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + (rechteckRechts.size.width / 2), y: frame.maxY / 1.25)
    rechteckLinks.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX - (rechteckLinks.size.width / 2), y: frame.maxY / 1.25)

    let moveDown = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -5000, duration: 20.0)
    rechteckLinks.run(moveDown)
    rechteckRechts.run(moveDown)

    self.addChild(rechteckRechts)
    self.addChild(rechteckLinks)
}
```

That way you add new ones each time. Also, delete

```
var rechteckRechts = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")
var rechteckLinks = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rechteck.gif")
```

from the top of the file since they have been added to the function. I also **strongly** suggest you use `SKAction` instead of `Timer` because it works well with sprite-kit. I would replace your timer code with this:

```
let wait1 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
let timer = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait1, SKAction.run {
        addRechteck()
    }]))
self.run(timer, withKey: "addRect")
```

Comment: Thank you. All the problems are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a timer that repeatedly calls the method `addRechteck`. The first time `addRechteck` is called, it adds two `SKSpriteNodes`:

```
self.addChild(rechteckRechts)
self.addChild(rechteckLinks)
```

Then, when this method is called again, it tries to add these two `SKSpriteNodes` a second time. This causes the error:

> Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent

Basically if an `SKSpriteNode` already has a parent you can't call `addChild` on it. You may want to check if the `SKSpriteNode` already has a parent, and if so, not add it.